# Select Option in AngularJS returning object not value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm still learning AngularJS, so im not quite sure as to the best way to implement this;
I'd be fine with doing this in ordinary HTML, but wasn't able to use the "selected" property, so i switched to an Angular  element - which im new to using.

I have a form, with a Drop down box, where the user selects either "User" or "Administrator".  A User has the value of "2", where Administrator has the value of "1".
By default, 'User' is the pre-selected item in the list.
My problem is, when the form is being submitted (via AJAX) to PHP, the form is submitting an Object like `{value : "2", name : "User"}` where i want it to just submit the value, ie: "2".

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="usrlevel">User Level:</label>
    <select class="form-control form-control-sm"
            data-ng-init="formData.usrlevel = usrlevels[0]"
            data-ng-model="formData.usrlevel"
            data-ng-options="x.name for x in usrlevels">
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
app.controller("admController", function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.usrlevels = [
      {value : "2", name : "User"},
      {value : "1", name : "Administrator"}
    ];

    $scope.addForm = function() {
        var ans="";
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : 'php/addstaff.php',
            data        : $.param($scope.formData),
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                ans = response.data;
                if (!ans.success) {
                    // Add Error handling

                } else {
                    $('#addModal').modal('hide');
                    $scope.getStaff();  //refreshes table display
                }
            }).catch(function(response){
                console.log(response.data);
            });
    };
```

And here's an image of the debugger, showing that for 'usrlevel' the form is submitting an object, when it should just be submitting the value of the selected item.
Thus, in the debugger, it should just be showing `usrlevel:"2"`
[image]

**UPDATE:**
As people seem to be under the impression that only the userlevel should be submitted by the AJAX call (I thought the debugger window image would make it clear that the userlevel is 1 element in the form) here's the actual HTML form.

```
<form data-ng-submit="addForm()" name="addform" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="name" data-ng-model="formData.name" id="name" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="address" data-ng-model="formData.address" id="address" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="suburb">Suburb:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="suburb" data-ng-model="formData.suburb" id="suburb" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="phone" data-ng-model="formData.phone" id="phone" placeholder="">
        </div>
    <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="postcode">Post Code:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="postcode" data-ng-model="formData.postcode" id="postcode" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="usrlevel">User Level:</label>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" data-ng-init="formData.usrlevel = usrlevels[0]" data-ng-model="formData.usrlevel" data-ng-options="x.name for x in usrlevels"></select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="email" data-ng-model="formData.email" id="email" placeholder="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="suburb">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="password" data-ng-model="formData.password" id="password" placeholder="">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<button type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-secondry">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others had mentioned, there was a problem with `ng-options` which is why it returned an object and not just the value.

But then, after changing `ng-options` it no longer had 'User' as the default selected item in the drop down - and this was then a problem with `ng-init`.

Old HTML

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm"
     data-ng-init="formData.usrlevel = usrlevels[0]"
     data-ng-model="formData.usrlevel"
     data-ng-options="x.name for x in usrlevels">
</select>
```

New HTML

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" 
   data-ng-model="formData.usrlevel" 
   data-ng-init="formData.usrlevel = formData.usrlevel || usrlevels[0].value"
   data-ng-options="x.value as x.name for x in usrlevels">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking why u get whole object on select and not only value selected.

This is because you used

```
 data-ng-options="x.name for x in usrlevels"
```

Which will set X to model on select, if you want only name/any other attr of x to be set to model you need to use

```
  data-ng-options="x.value as x.name for x in usrlevels" data-ng-model="formData.value"
```

As tell angular select x show it as y.

### to make default selection work

now you need to update `$score.formData.value` with value of selected user object.

so forexample in ur controller

```
app.controller("admController", function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.usrlevels = [
      {value : "2", name : "User"},
      {value : "1", name : "Administrator"}
    ];
    $scope.formData = { value: "1"} // prepare formData and set user with value 1 (Admin) to be selected by default
```

### finally send whole formData.

```
http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'php/addstaff.php',
        data        : $scope.formData,
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        }).then(function (response) {
            ...etc
```

Again pass only wt u need to data of ajax, dont pass whole object!

Comment: While changing 'data-ng-options' as you suggested works (and only submits the value), it also breaks the 'default selected'.
So how would i then have it, so that by default 'User' is the selected item?

As to the suggestion to change the AJAX;
Refer my update ~ it HAS TO submit the entire form, as I don't want just one element of the form submitted!!!!

Comment: @BlissSol updated answer. the point is dont polute your formData with properties you dont want to send in form, use any other variable. or process $scope.formData to filter out unneeded properties -you may even consider doing so to validate form before sending it !-

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your model. Well, an easy to understand syntax would look like this

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller('ctrl', function($scope){

 $scope.users= [{value : "2", name : "User"},{value : "1", name : "Admin"}]
 $scope.user = "2";
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" >
<select ng-model="user">
  <option ng-repeat="i in users" value="{{i.value}}">{{i.name}}</option>
</select>
Value is : {{user}}
</div>
```

And now you can use `$scope.user` as selected value to send wherever you want.

To send it as payload to your request, you can use something like

```
..
data : {"userLevel" :$scope.user },
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `as` clause in `ng-options`:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="usrlevel">User Level:</label>
    <select class="form-control form-control-sm"
            ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶-̶n̶g̶-̶i̶n̶i̶t̶=̶"̶f̶o̶r̶m̶D̶a̶t̶a̶.̶u̶s̶r̶l̶e̶v̶e̶l̶ ̶=̶ ̶u̶s̶r̶l̶e̶v̶e̶l̶s̶[̶0̶]̶"̶
            data-ng-model="formData.usrlevel"
            ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶-̶n̶g̶-̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶=̶"̶x̶.̶n̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶x̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶u̶s̶r̶l̶e̶v̶e̶l̶s̶"̶>̶
            data-ng-options="x.value as x.name for x in usrlevels">
    </select>
</div>
```

Also the initial value of the `ng-model` should be set to a primitive instead of an object:

```
$scope.formData.usrlevel = $scope.usrlevels[0].value;
```

---

It is better to POST data as `application/json`, but if your backend only supports `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, use the AngularJS built-in param serializer:

```
$scope.addForm = function() {
    var ans="";
    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'php/addstaff.php',
        ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶:̶ ̶$̶.̶p̶a̶r̶a̶m̶(̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶f̶o̶r̶m̶D̶a̶t̶a̶)̶,̶
        data    : $scope.formData,
        transformRequest: $httpParamSerializerJQLike,
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
    })
```

Comment: But this will then no longer have 'User' as the default selected item in the control.

Comment: Updated answer.